# Can anyone tell me what these two equations represent?

Tags: thermodynamics, lenses

I've just seen these without any explanation of what the variables are or what are do they describe, I just know it should be something about convex lenses and starting fire with them.

$$Q_r=C^n(-\Delta H_r)Ze^{-\frac{E}{RT}}$$

I'm not sure if the triangle represents delta as change or if it's a Laplace operator

$$C_p\rho\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=Q_r-Q_c$$

Can anyone tell me what the variables are and what do these equations represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the source?

Broadly, the first is an [Arrhenius equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrhenius_equation), which provides the rate of a thermally activated process, i.e., one with an activation energy.

$Q_r$: a rate (based on the second equation, likely a heat flux)
$C^n$: some type of pre-exponential factor, where n may be the reaction order; problem specific
$-\Delta H_r$: H often stands for enthalpy and r for reaction
$Z$: typically a collision frequency
$E$: the activation energy
$R$: the gas constant
$T$: the temperature

The second equation is a heat capacity equation describing how an object heats up from a net heat flux.

$C_p$: specific heat capacity at constant pressure
$\rho$: density
$t$: time
$Q_r$: likely an input heat flux, with units of J/m³s
$Q_c$: likely an output heat flux, perhaps to a cold sink (c)

Put together, the equations provide an energy balance: the thermal energy generated from a reaction minus any output thermal energy goes into heating the system.